# jQuery on electron main process

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, electron

How I can use jQuery on electron main process?

It seems every example I find is for renderer process.

Example I want to create a util that will be used by the main process, that will fetch data from an api using get.

Then using `$.get` makes an error that `get is not a function`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a JS library for the browser, eg DOM manipulating, etc. You shouldn't use that in the main process, since the main process is running in [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org).

It's hard to propose a solution without knowing more about your application. If you need the data from the AJAX request in your main process, you can use [NodeJS https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) package. Example from [Twilio blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html):

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

**Edit:**
As @Hans-Koch mentioned, you probably shouldn't use jQuery in the renderer process either since one of it's main purpose is to normalize the API for DOM manipulation, AJAX, etc. and in Electron you only have to support Chromium. If you want to make AJAX request you can use the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or some npm package which wraps it, eg [xhr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr).

Comment: Even at the render process jQuery is the wrong approch, it does normalized DOM manipulation there is no point to normalize if there is only a single target browser (chromium)

Comment: @HansKoch I didn't get it. What do you mean "there is no point to normalize if there is only a single target browser"? Ho about I am gonna use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to fetch the data, then use jquery to update part of the page? or Is there any other way around? thanks.

Comment: What Hans mean is that jQuery "normalize" the interface to the browsers. So a call to IE10 would look the same as when you're calling Chrome, Safari or Firefox. In Electron our only target is Chromium, so the normalization isn't needed. `request` should work just fine :)

Comment: Exactly that :)

Comment: How to use `https` module to get non-https URL
?