# Electron-packager Javascript Error (jQuery)

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-packager

I have problems compiling my (first) electron project...

I could successfully create the new folder with the compiled app, however, when trying to open the executable a pop-up comes up stating:

A Javascript Error occured in the main process

Uncaught Expectation: $ is not defined at.......

I have tried [this](http://electron.rocks/library-is-not-defined/) solution but it doesnt change anything.

```
  <!--Hack to fix library not defined (pt. 1)-->
  <script>
    if (typeof module === 'object') {
      window.module = module;
      module = undefined;
    }
  </script>

  <!--Library-->
  <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

  <!--Hack to fix library not defined (pt. 2)-->
  <script>
    if (window.module) module = window.module;
  </script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you provide the relevant part of your code?

Comment: I dont think there is a relevant part of the code other than the link I've referred to. I'll include the script in my question!

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery in the main process, check out this answer to read more why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885019/jquery-on-electron-main-process/46889308#46889308

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I was at work.

I solved installing *jQuery* by npm

```
npm i jquery --save
```

And importing by require

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
</script>
```

You can also download it and inform the directory

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require("path/to/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js);
</script>
```

Check in working

[image: jQuery Working]

Sorry my bad English.

Comment: While this could be the perfect solution for the OP, it would be beneficial to get some extra information. Just posting a code snippet is imho not a good way to answer a question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've implemented the code to my main.js, however, I dont know how to get the factory part to work since I've never worked with it before.

Comment: Thank you but I think you misunderstood my question. I got jquery to work successfully but when I package my project and try to open it, it gives me an error that $ is undefined...

Comment: See the order you are importing the packages. First import the jQuery then the packages that depend on it